# How to delete data in FlutterUI through JSON?

Tags: json, django, api, dart, flutter

Basically what I want is to remove a specific data in my Django database.
This is how I got the JSON in Flutter:

```
Future<String> getData() async{
http.Response response= await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull("192.168.2.107:8000/api/"),
    headers: {
      "Accept" : "application/JSON"
    }
);
```

I just can't figure out how to delete an entry (e.g. "192.168.2.107:8000/api/**16**"). Something that I've found is this https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient/delete.html but I don't quite understand what I am supposed to insert.

Just if needed my urls.py :

```
url(r'^api/(?P<image_id>\d+)/$', views.get_rest_list,name='api'),

url(r'^api/delete/(?P<image_id>\d+)/$', views.delete,name='apiDelete'),
```

I hope I described the issue correctly.

Comment: Delete over http: await.delete(host, port, path) and set the headers like in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Python you posted, it seems like you have an `api` and an `apiDelete` url, so probably you want to change:

```
192.168.2.107:8000/api/
```

to

```
192.168.2.107:8000/apiDelete/
```

However, I'm not sure how your server is working - if it allows you to delete using a GET request (`http.get` issues a GET request) you probably want to figure out how to change it to use a `DELETE` request and then use `http.delete` instead (or at least, a `POST` and use `http.post`).

Comment: Well now it works with the http.get. Would it make a big difference if I would use DELETE (or POST)? Is it more secure or more efficient? Or is it just a good practice to do so? Ouh and thx for your answer :)

Comment: The spec says GET requests shouldn't have side-effects like this. Browser may pre-fetch or re-request resources using GET on a whim. For example, [this thread](https://twitter.com/rombulow/status/990684453734203392) describes someone who used a GET request for his garage door opener and found it opening on its own "randomly". The risk may seem low (especially if this URL only appears in your app), but I'd definitely recommend learning to do it right so in future you know how to do it and don't have to worry about how risky it is.